# Subtract string from binary NSData on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, nsstring, nsdata

I have a NSData of bytes from where I want to subtract a string. The NSData object looks like this

```
01 00 00 04 40 00 00 00 00 41 41 41 41 48 47 5A 30 65 58 42 4E 4E 45 45 67 41 
41 41 41 41 45 30 30 51 53 42 74 63 44 51 79 61 58 4E 76 62 51 41 41 41 2B 39 
74 62 32 39 32 41 41 41 41 62 47 31 32 61 47 51 41 41 41 41 41 71 67 59 35 79 
36 6F 47 4F 63 73 41 41 4B 78 45 41 41 43 34 41 41 41 42 41 41 41 42 41 41 41 
41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 51 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41
```

I want to extract everything from the first occurrence of "40 00 00 00" to the first occurrence of "34"

How can I do that?

Thanks

marc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure which bytes you want, here is extracted data in the range between  "40 00 00 00" to the first occurrence of "34" and the data with that range removed:

```
const NSUInteger dataLength = 130;
unsigned char dataBytes[dataLength] = {
0x01,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x40,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x48,0x47,0x5A,
0x30,0x65,0x58,0x42,0x4E,0x4E,0x45,0x45,0x67,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x45,0x30,
0x30,0x51,0x53,0x42,0x74,0x63,0x44,0x51,0x79,0x61,0x58,0x4E,0x76,0x62,0x51,0x41,
0x41,0x41,0x2B,0x39,0x74,0x62,0x32,0x39,0x32,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x62,0x47,0x31,
0x32,0x61,0x47,0x51,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x71,0x67,0x59,0x35,0x79,0x36,0x6F,
0x47,0x4F,0x63,0x73,0x41,0x41,0x4B,0x78,0x45,0x41,0x41,0x43,0x34,0x41,0x41,0x41,
0x42,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x42,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,
0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x51,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,
0x41,0x41};
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:dataBytes length:130];

const NSUInteger startBytesLength = 4;
unsigned char startBytes[startBytesLength] = {0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
const NSUInteger stopBytesLength = 1;
unsigned char stopBytes[stopBytesLength] = {0x34};


NSData *startData = [NSData dataWithBytes:startBytes length:startBytesLength];
NSData *stopData  = [NSData dataWithBytes:stopBytes  length:stopBytesLength];
NSRange startRange = [data rangeOfData:startData options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, dataLength)];
NSUInteger start = startRange.location;

NSRange stopRange  = [data rangeOfData:stopData  options:0 range:NSMakeRange(start+startBytesLength, dataLength-(start+startBytesLength))];
NSUInteger length = stopRange.location - start;
NSUInteger stopLocation = stopRange.location+stopBytesLength;

NSData *extractData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(start, length)];
NSLog(@"extractData: %@", extractData);

NSMutableData *newData = [NSMutableData data];
[newData appendData:[data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, start)]];
[newData appendData:[data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(stopLocation, dataLength-stopLocation)]];
NSLog(@"newData: %@", newData);
```

NSLog output:

> extractData: <00414141 4148475a 30655842 4e4e4545 67414141 41414530
>   30515342 74634451 7961584e 76625141 41412b39 74623239 32414141
>   41624731 32614751 41414141 41716759 3579366f 474f6373 41414b78
>   45414143>
>
> newData: <01000004 41414142 41414142 41414141 41414141 41414141
>   41414141 41514141 41414141 41414141 41>

Comment: The first output is what I need (`extractData`). It extracts exactly what I need, but crashes at the end of the function (`malloc: *** error for object 0xbfffd6cf: pointer being freed was not allocated`). Do you know what is it?

Comment: Adding `freeWhenDone:NO`in the `startData` and `stopData` declaration solved the issue.

Comment: Oops, I should not have used the NoCopy version, that requires the character arrays to have been allocated with malloc. Fixed.